# BizTalk set up in dual center environment

Tags: architecture, installation, biztalk

I have a question with setting up BizTalk clustered servers in both dual center.  We have a data center in South of CA and North of CA.  We want both BizTalk servers to be running at both dual center, possibly doing the same things.  If there's a problem with one of the data center, then the other server will pick up the work.

My question is should we set up one BizTalk cluster at each data center, or create one Biztalk cluster that includes the Biztalk servers from both South and North?   Given the our requirement to have both of them running and doing the same thing, which one makes more sense?

Thanks in advance!!

Angela

Comment: Good Q - ENTSSO failover and SQL availability might dissuade from the distributed single cluster scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the servers doing the same thing you need for the servers to be part of the same Biztalk cluster. That is Biztalk front end servers that are pointing to the same database.

Say you place the database in the North data center, then if the South data center goes down, the North will continue to work. But if the North goes down, the South will stop since there is no database. You then need some strategy to ship your database over continually and then switch to a copy.

To get the above working is a lot of work. Then the option of a seperate Biztalk cluster at each site makes more sense. But you need to configure some routing such that what is added to one cluster is transfered to the other.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, since the bottle neck might be the database, so it makes sense to have 2 different independent setups.